# Populate dropdown list dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint 2010, jquery-1.9.0.min.js and need to populate asp dropdown list based on users' AD groups. I already have the code getting AD groups and getting the values that need to go into dropdown list. The dropdown list would have any combination of 2 to 4 items (text and values), then selected item should flow into the web parts on the same web page. I'm new to SharePoint/jquery and not sure how setup the dropdown list options dynamically. I had setup dropdown list with bogus texts and values and need to replace it with valid values for each user. I'd like to use jquery if possible. If there is another simpler way - please let me know. I'd need to know how to add 1 or 2 additional options if needed.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem value="06">Fac1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem value ="07">Fac2</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: What have you tried? It really shouldn't be hard to find numerous results for doing this in a web search

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax of the command to refer to options of the dropdown list. Most code that I found only tells me how to select the item that was chosen from existing dropdown list, not populate the list. Tried few different ways. $("#DropDownList1 option:text=" + Somename +"").prop("selected", "selected"); 
$("input[id$=DropDownList1]").text("Somename");
$("#Dropdownlist1").val("thevalue");

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example:
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/

...and a code sample from the blog. In your case, "#ddlGender" should be populated with the .ClientID property of your DropDownList control and you'll need to tweak the call and processing to fit your specific situation:

```
$().ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetGenders",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#ddlGender").get(0).options.length = 0;
            $("#ddlGender").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select gender", "-1");   

            $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                $("#ddlGender").get(0).options[$("#ddlGender").get(0).options.length] 
                      = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Failed to load genders");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I had googled the population of the dropdown of course. Solutions seem complicated, when the task itself is easy. I was hoping to find the code that would tell me how to update the dropdown list items (options) on load with jquery. In the example above it specifies exact url, but for my situation I pass the parameters in the url and each user might have a unique parameters in the url. I'm also not familiar with "json". It seems that it should be really easy, if you know how to correctly refer to the dropdown list. All coding is done in SharePoint Designer, using web parts that came with it.

Comment: I think I figured out the command. Also switched dropdown from asp to html dropdown (#FacilList). Now facing new issue - first url parameter cuts off only first character (value), while next url parameter has the whole word. Tried to rename parameters in url - no difference. What causes it? if (document.URL.indexOf("Facnam1") != -1) {
fname = $.urlParam('Facnam1'); 
var str="<option value='" +fnum + "'>" +fname + "</option>";
$("#FacilList").append(str);
}

Comment: I had resolved the url problem as well - found different code to get parameters. New issue - drop down list is reloaded every time any filter value is updated and losing the value that user had just chosen. How to load drop down list once or at least make sure that selected value stays? Tried to store it in a variable, but it is wiped out with each reload. The other question - how to remove value from SharePoint filter? Tried to assign it like this $("input[id$='SpListFilterWebPart']").text(''); but it is not working